# VB.NET Grid view with variable button text

Tags: vb.net, button, gridview

How can I make the text of a button in a Gridview change depending on the values in the gridview

For example, in the code below, how can I set the button text to YOUNG for rows where the age is below 40 and OLD for rows above or equal to 40

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_DataByGroupAct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Hight" HeaderText="Hight" />
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Young/Old" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `TemplateField` with a real `Button` control and `RowDataBound` for your logic:

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_DataByGroupAct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Hight" HeaderText="Hight" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Button ID="BtnYoungOld" runat="server" Text="Young/Old" />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

codebehind:

```
Private Sub GV_DataByGroupAct_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GV_DataByGroupAct.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
            Dim row = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
            Dim age As Int32 = Int32.Parse(row("age").ToString)
            Dim BtnYoungOld = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("BtnYoungOld"), Button)
            BtnYoungOld.Text = If(age < 40, "YOUNG", "OLD")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on e.row.FindControl... :Value of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

Comment: @Selrac: Why do you have a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in a web-project?? Then you either have to remove it(you never need windows forms in ASP.NET) or you have to specify the full namespace: `DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("BtnYoungOld"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)`.

Comment: I've changed DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("BtnYoungOld"), Button) to DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("Comment"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) and it worked for me. Thanks Tim for the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `RowDataBound` event of the grid view so you can alter the content of the button text on each row as it is bound, like this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As [Object], e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' Put logic here to check age and then update button text
    End If
End Sub
```